# Cumulative logic in oracle with Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written the following query but it's not working in running total
 column, I need all records for the dates mentioned below and for each ID, I 
 need cumumative totals for first 21 days and the number of records for 21 
 days, executing in oracle

```
SELECT (TO_DATE (MIN (date_ref_key), 'YYYYMMDD')),
       id,
       (TO_DATE (MIN (date_ref_key), 'YYYYMMDD')) + 21,
       SUM (
          Deposit_Amount)
       OVER (PARTITION BY id
             ORDER BY (TO_DATE (MIN (date_ref_key), 'YYYYMMDD')) <(to_date(min(date_ref_key),'YYYYMMDD'))+21) running_total
     from performance.fact_paymentsystems@cis_prod_link
      WHERE sort='Deposit' and
     date_ref_key>=20140831 and date_ref_key<20160901
     and status='Done'
     GROUP BY ID
     order by min(date_ref_key)
```

Input

```
id  date_ref_key    Amount
1   01/09/2014  10
1   02/09/2014  10
1   03/09/2014  10
1   04/09/2014  10
1   05/09/2014  10
1   06/09/2014  10
1   07/09/2014  10
1   08/09/2014  10
1   09/09/2014  10
1   10/09/2014  10
1   11/09/2014  10
1   12/09/2014  10
1   13/09/2014  10
1   14/09/2014  10
1   15/09/2014  10
1   16/09/2014  10
1   17/09/2014  10
1   18/09/2014  10
1   19/09/2014  10
1   20/09/2014  10
1   21/09/2014  10
1   22/09/2014  10
1   23/09/2014  10
1   24/09/2014  10
2   01/09/2014  10
2   02/09/2014  10
2   01/09/2012  10
2   02/09/2012  10
2   03/09/2012  10
2   04/09/2012  10
2   05/09/2012  10
2   06/09/2012  10
2   07/09/2012  10
2   08/09/2012  10
2   09/09/2012  10
2   10/09/2012  10
2   11/09/2012  10
2   12/09/2012  10
2   13/09/2012  10
2   14/09/2012  10
2   15/09/2012  10
2   16/09/2012  10
2   17/09/2012  10
2   18/09/2012  10
2   19/09/2012  10
2   20/09/2012  10
2   21/09/2012  10
2   22/09/2012  10
3   01/01/2015  10
3   02/01/2015  10
3   03/01/2015  10
3   04/01/2015  10
3   05/01/2015  10
3   06/01/2015  10
3   07/01/2015  10
3   08/01/2015  10
3   09/01/2015  10
3   10/01/2015  10
3   11/01/2015  10
3   12/01/2015  10
3   13/01/2015  10
3   14/01/2015  10
3   15/01/2015  10
3   16/01/2015  10
3   17/01/2015  10
3   18/01/2015  10
3   19/01/2015  10
3   20/01/2015  10
3   21/01/2015  10
3   22/01/2015  10
3   23/01/2015  10
3   24/01/2015  10
```

Output

```
ID  Amount COUNTOF IDS'S (SHOULD ALSO COUNT DUPLICATES IF PRESENT)
1   210   21
3   210   21
```

Comment: Please give sample data and your expected output based on that.

Comment: Something useful on how to build a [mcve]

Comment: Your expected result sounds strange to me; in your sample data there are no rows with ID = 3

Comment: Apologies its a typo changed it now

Comment: Your sample just raises more question. Can you please do below.
1) Instead of `21` days, use `3` or `4` days for example, which will be more realistic. We can later replace `3` or `4` with `21`.
2) What would happen if you have days missing in the sequence?
3) Should u always consider first `21` days of months? What if same id is spanned across multiple months. 

Try to recreated a small example and expected result so we can try to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: If you go from "date" to "date + 21" that will be 22 days, not 21. Then: do you want one GLOBAL start date (which is why you don't have id=2 in the output)? It seems so; just making sure. The big mistake for sure, and probably explaining your issues, is the ORDER BY clause in the sum; you should order by date, not by min(date). The min(date) is the same for all rows, so the ordering is in fact ABSOLUTELY RANDOM - you get 21 or 22 random amounts being added up.

Comment: cumulative amounts for ID should be calculated for consecutive 21 days, it  needs to calcluate from initial entry and from there for consecutive next 21 days, anytime after 21 days it should ignore

Comment: Hi mathguy, I know that we cannot use aggregated functions in the partition by statement, can you help me out in writing a query